# exclude transitive plugin dependencies

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, dependency-management

I've installed the [asynchronous mail plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/asynchronous-mail) into a Grails 2.1.4 application. This plugin has a dependency on version 2.1.1 of the Hibernate plugin, whereas my app depends on version 2.1.4 of the Hibernate plugin.

Every time I execute a Grails command like `run-app`, I am asked the following question:

> You currently already have a version of the plugin installed [hibernate-2.1.4]. Do you want to update to [hibernate-2.1.1]? [y,n] n

I know that `run-app` has an `--non-interactive` argument, but AFAIK this will automatically answer `y` to this question. Ideally, I would like to solve this problem by excluding the transitive Hibernate plugin dependency from the asynchronous mail plugin, but transitive dependency exclusion only seems to be possible for JAR dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs in the plugin page are wrong - you need this for any Grails app not using version 2.1.1, not just older apps:

```
compile(":asynchronous-mail:1.0-RC3") {
   excludes 'hibernate'
}
```